# save and use value from chrome.sync.storage.get()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I'm writing a small extension on chrome and I'm trying to use chrome.storage.
On my options page I saved some info that I will get on the content_script:

On `options.js`

```
function save_options() {
      var color = document.getElementById('color').value;
      chrome.storage.sync.set({
        favoriteColor: color
      }, function() {
        console.log("Color saved");
      });
    }
```

But I have problem for use this information on my `content_script.js`. I tried:

```
    var color = null;
    chrome.storage.sync.get('favoriteColor', function(item){
        color = item.favoriteColor;
        //alert(color); //Here works;
});

alert(color); // here doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

**[chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)** is asynchronous meaning the alert it beeing executed even before the variable **color** is defined, that's why you always get undefined. You need to wait until the **get** method is finished. You can set a callback function in your content_script.js that is executed only after the color is defined:

```
    var color = null;
        chrome.storage.sync.get('favoriteColor', function(item){
            color = item.favoriteColor;
            alertColor(color);
    });

    function alertColor(color){
        alert(color);
    }
```